# Pattern evaluater

Tags: java, design-patterns, binary-tree, expression-evaluation

I have some a string which needed to be evaluated in following pattern -

```
Input  => String testTree = "(1(2(4)())(3))";   
Output => {1,2,3,4,*,*,*}

Input  => String testTree2 = "(1(2(4)(5))(3()(4()(3))))";   
Output => {1,2,3,4,5,*,4,*,*,*,*,*,*,*,3}

Input  => String testTree3 = "(1()())";   
Output =>{1,*,*}
```

Above mention inputs have same pattern , where '()' or null is represented as '*****'.Output is been saved to a int/string array , hence output form is like so.

Kindly suggest a method to evaluate such kind of pattern to the output form.

Comment: Why you added `binary-tree` tag?

Comment: Take a look at the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Comment: This problem is a part of Binary tree generation , if see carefully the input cases are kind of binary tree string notation and the output is leve- order form of the input.

Comment: Is it possible to use stack?

Comment: There is no need of creating a binary tree here , its just i want to evaluate the input to output using some kind of logic , it can be hard coded too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Interpreter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_pattern) to read the input into a binary tree class.